# Regarding SQL Query for asp.net application

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am new in SQL as well as ASP.NET. For one of my projects I need the following output [requried output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G7Vy.png). So far I have done this [my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBo1G.png). But here some Test Type Name is repeating. How to solve this problem?

My current query:

```
SELECT 
    tyi.TestType, 
    COUNT(tr.TestID) AS NoOfTest,
    (Fee*COUNT(tr.TestID)) AS TotalAmount,
FROM
    TestTypeInfo AS tyi 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TestInfo AS ti ON
             tyi.TestTypeId=ti.TestTypeId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TestRequest tr ON
             ti.TestId=tr.TestId
WHERE
    EntryDate BETWEEN '2016-12-31' AND '2016-12-31' OR
    EntryDate IS NULL
GROUP BY
    tyi.TestType
```

Which gives me the output:

```
TestType      | NoOfTest | TotalAmount
---------------------------------------
ECG           | 4        | 600
X-Ray         | 4        | 800
Blood         | 6        | 1800
X-Ray         | 4        | 1200
Echo          | 4        | 4000
X-Ray         | 3        | 3300
Echo          | 0        | 0
UltraSonogram | 0        | 0
```

Comment: As per your query , you have done group by testtype and fee. You are getting different row for Xray because there would 3 different fees for Xray and thats evident from the total fees column. If you remove the fee column from select n group by clause , you would be getting single row for the testtypes

Comment: @Rajat Mishra, but then how can I get the Total Amount for a particular Test Type?

Comment: You could aggregate fee, would sum(Fee) AS TotalAmount help you?

Hard to say without viewing the raw data.

Comment: @ramzanali you need to use a subquery for that

Comment: @LudvigRydahl That was one hell of an edit. Good job. Approved.

Comment: @MYGz Haha, thanks! I simply hate reading badly structured code, as well as not being able to just copy it. Code should be placed within a code block and structured for easy reading IMHO :)

Comment: @LudvigRydahl, really great Edit, I will follow your style from next time.

Comment: @ramzanali There's a lot of different styles to write SQL in, I prefer this one since I find it really easy to separate different clauses, and furthermore different components within those clauses, such as columns, tables and conditions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this should help you. Please check the column names once.

```
Select a.TestType , Sum(a.NoOfTest) , Sum(a.TotalAmount) from 
(Select tyi.TestType As TestType , Count(tr.testId) As NoOfTest, 
(Fee*Count(tr.testId)) As TotalAmount 
From TestTypeInfo As tyi 
Left Outer Join TestInfo As ti on tyi.TestTypeId = ti.TestTypeId 
Left Outer Join TestRequest tr on ti.TestId = tr.TestId 
Where EntryDate between '2016-12-31' and '2016-12-31' 
or EntryDate is null group by tyi.TestType, Fee) a 
Group by a.TestType
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get multiple posts for each TestType is because you use Fee in group by. This leads to that if Fee would be different in any one row, it would cause that row to post as a separate result row.

If I understand correctly (hard to say without viewing the raw data) you want to show how many tests, and the fee for all these tests, for say Xray.

Would not following suffice?

```
SELECT 
    tyi.TestType, 
    COUNT(tr.TestID) AS NoOfTest,
    sum(Fee) as TotalAmount,
FROM
    TestTypeInfo AS tyi 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TestInfo AS ti ON
        tyi.TestTypeId=ti.TestTypeId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TestRequest tr ON 
        ti.TestId=tr.TestId
WHERE
    EntryDate BETWEEN '2016-12-31' AND '2016-12-31' OR
    EntryDate IS NULL
GROUP BY
    tyi.TestType
```

This of course depends on how TotalAmount should be calculated.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  your ans was good. But there are some problem (1.) For TestType with No NoOfTest the TotalAmount is also showing instead of showing zero. (2.) Some TotalAmount is not correct. I am trying to add the new screenshot

Comment: As i stated, it is very hard to know how the computed columns should be created, since we don't know how the raw data looks, and how the output is expected to look. It would be a lot easier to give a good example if you could pull out some example data, and how you would like that example data to be look when run through the query.

Comment: I've also edited my answer, since I missed a Left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the fee column from main query . Then use the correlated sub query for total amount with join of fee id.